# Component function as Ajax callback

Tags: ajax, typescript, angular

I have a menu component that use Ajax call for dynamic HTML rendering, so the browser won't refresh when the user click on one of the menu item. We use jQuery-ajax-unobtrusive to perform the Ajax call. This part works well.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Some HTML ... -->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/Home/Contact"
                       data-ajax="true"
                       data-ajax-method="GET"
                       data-ajax-mode="replace"
                       data-ajax-success="setUrl"
                       data-ajax-failure="redirectToLogin"
                       data-ajax-update="#renderbody">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I use Ajax callback like this

```
data-ajax-success="setUrl"
data-ajax-failure="redirectToLogin"
```

I was wondering if these callbacks can be encapsulated in Angular2' component functions written in Typescript ? For the moment, I have a Javascript error telling that it cannot found methods 'setUrl' and 'redirectToLogin'.

Comment: So the function is called by the name passed to `data-ajax-success`. You need to assign a reference to `setUrl()` in the context where the ajax code looks for it. I don't know the jQuery ajax library and can't help here. Goging to delete my answer. AFAIR there was a similar question related to some Google-API (maps I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation of this within a custom Angular2 directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[data-ajax]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick($event)'
  }
})
export class DataAjaxDirective {
  @Input('href')
  url:string;
  @Input('data-ajax')
  enabled:boolean;
  @Input('dataAjaxMethod')
  method:string;
  @Input('dataAjaxMode')
  mode:string;
  @Output('data-ajax-success')
  success:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output('data-ajax-failure')
  failure:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.http[this.method.toLowerCase()](this.url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.success.emit(data);
      },
      (err) => {
        this.failure.emit(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And the way to use it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <a href="https://mapapi.apispark.net/v1/maps/"
                   data-ajax="true"
                   dataAjaxMethod="GET"
                   dataAjaxMode="replace"
                   (data-ajax-success)="onDataReceived($event)"
                   (data-ajax-failure)="redirectToLogin()"
                   data-ajax-update="#renderbody">Contact</a>

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#map of maps">{{map.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ DataAjaxDirective ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  onDataReceived(data) {
    this.maps = data;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Csw9bq7Ufa3bGXkqpSyN?p=preview.

Comment: Nice solution ! With my own implementation of the jQuery plugin this could works ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

JQuery needs global `setUrl` function: `window.setUrl = function(){};` which is not way to go.

You could write your own implementation of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js using custom `Directive`.